# How to draw a DiGraph in a Org Chart fashion?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, pygraphviz, digraphs

**issue statement:**

While I managed to get a chart out of a Networkx DiGraph via Matplotlib, I wish I could get better settings or be advised a more suitable library to draw it in a more 'readable' fashion.

As you'll see below, the chart is pretty much skewed and edges are not much distinct from one each other. This need to be corrected.

---

## AS-IS:

the list of edges and the current chart is drawn with nx.kamada_kawai_layout and plt.show

**list of edges :**

```py
[('D', 'N', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 3}), ('D', 'I', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 3}), ('D', 'E', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 1}), ('I', 'J', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2}), ('L', 'M', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2}), ('G', 'H', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2}), ('H', 'C', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 1}), ('C', 'D', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2}), ('C', 'K', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 1}), ('B', 'C', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2}), ('A', 'B', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2}), ('K', 'L', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2}), ('E', 'F', {'fam': 2, 'weight': 2})]
```

**list of nodes :**

```py
[('D', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('N', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'yes', 'root': 'no'}), ('I', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('L', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('M', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'yes', 'root': 'no'}), ('J', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'yes', 'root': 'no'}), ('G', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'yes'}), ('H', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('C', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('B', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('A', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'yes'}), ('K', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('E', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'no', 'root': 'no'}), ('F', {'fam': 2, 'leaf': 'yes', 'root': 'no'})]
```

**the chart :**
[image: nx.kamada_kawai_layout]

**current code to draw the chart:**

```py
elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in g.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] == 3 ]
enormal = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in g.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] == 2 ]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in g.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] == 1 ]

nleaf = [(u) for (u, d) in g.nodes(data=True) if d['leaf'] == 'yes' ]
nroot = [(u) for (u, d) in g.nodes(data=True) if d['root'] == 'yes' ]

edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight']) for u,v,d in g.edges(data=True)])

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(g)


# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, node_size=200)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, nodelist=nleaf, node_color='g', node_size=600)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, nodelist=nroot, node_color='y', node_size=600)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=elarge, width=2, alpha=0.8, edge_color='g', style='dotted')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=enormal, width=2, alpha=0.8, edge_color='b', style='dashed')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=esmall, width=2, alpha=0.8, edge_color='b', style='solid')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif')


plt.axis('off')
N = 2
params = plt.gcf()
plSize = params.get_size_inches()
params.set_size_inches( (plSize[0]*N, plSize[1]*N) )
plt.show()
```

---

### TO-BE

directionally, I would like to get something like the below.

note:

- what matter is the overall shape, not the color
- the chart/layout setup should be applicable not only the for example provided above but for any DiGraph of 'reasonable' size (i.e. ~20edges)

[image: org-chart like drawing]

---

### *thanks a lot in advance for your time and feedbacks !*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [graphviz layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html#networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout) for proper graph visualization. Replace this line of code:

`pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(g)`

with this:

`pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(g, prog='dot')`

It uses DOT engine from the graphviz, which is amazing for directed graphs, especially DAGs and trees. Note that you need Graphviz to be installed on your machine for this function usage.

I altered your `draw` code with this (only affects colors/sizes):

```
# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, node_size=500, node_color='#AAAAAA')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, nodelist=nleaf, node_color='#00BB00', node_size=800)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, nodelist=nroot, node_color='#9999FF', node_size=800)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=elarge, width=2, alpha=0.8, edge_color='g', style='dotted')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=enormal, width=2, alpha=0.8, edge_color='b', style='dashed')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=esmall, width=2, alpha=0.8, edge_color='b', style='solid')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, font_size=14, font_color='w', font_family='sans-serif')
```

And it draws the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The chart you draw with the pygraphviz module is totally aligned with expectations. The only concern I face is the difficulty to install that library on my business machine (x64 Win10 missing visual  C++ 14). I hope I can manage it asap. Or find a workaround via Palantir.

Comment: Wow, I haven't known that Palantir is used outside USA! I am sure it has some kind of visualization for DAGs but I can't help you with it. Pygraphviz on Win10 x64 is really a problem but it is the only good library you can use with networkx. If it will not work, you will have to export your graph to some format and visualize it with another programs, like Gephi.

Comment: Hi Vurmux, I managed to draw the Graph with your provided answer in the Palantir Code Workbook. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide me your email, if you don't mind? I have been interested in Palantir for a long time, but I didn't found any info about Palantir Code Workbook.